# Google Home Control Fan

Tags: google-home, google-smart-home

I have linked my fan to Google Home, and I can see my fan on Google Home App. The problem is that I can only control and speed control my fan by saying to Google. I didn't find any button or bar to manually control my fan on Google Home App. Other types of device such as light and socket all can be manually controlled on Google Home App, but I can't find any controlling button for Fan. is there need specific query response for device of fan type?

Answer (score 0):

`On/Off` is currently the only recommended `Fan` trait that has touch controls enabled in the Google Home app. You can see [the list of other traits and device types](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/touch-controls) that have touch controls enabled.

You can check [the public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=655104&template=1284148) to see if someone has already requested the particular traits you'd like to see supported (such as `FanSpeed`) and subscribe for updates, or file a request for touch control support if the issue has not yet been filed.